# Simple solution to No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource?

Tags: jquery, ajax, request, cors

I'm kinda new to the world of connecting to APIs and ajax requests and so. I'm trying to send a POST ajax call to an API on the server but I'm getting this error when I send it from my machine:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.

But if script runs from the hosted server, then I don't get this error. Of course I read about this issue in many questions here, but I'm unable to execute any of the solutions due to so many weird terms that I wasn't able to understand. I tried many of those solutions as I understood them, but they didn't work.

One of the proposed solutions is "to add a header to the response". So I tried it like this but it didn't work:

```
function ajax_insert(data, success_func, error_func) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: the_url,
        data: data,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        xhrFields: {
          withCredentials: true
        },
        success: function(response) {
            response = HttpResponse(json.dumps('{"status" : "success"}'))
            response.__setitem__("Content-type", "application/json")
            response.__setitem__("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            success_func(response)
        },
        error: function(xhr){
            error_func(xhr)
        }
    });

}
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: As far as *“add a header to the response”*, you can’t do that on the client side from your frontend Javascript the way the code snippet in the question seems to be attempting. So you need to remove the whole `success: function(response)` block there. It’s not doing anything for you.

Comment: *“The response had HTTP status code 405”* means the server you’re making the request to is responding with “method not allowed”, which means either it’s not configured to allow POST requests to the URL in the request, or else it’s not configured to allow OPTIONS requests.

Comment: The `contentType: application/json; charset=UTF-8` header your code is adding to the request triggers your browser to first automatically do a [CORS preflight OPTIONS request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) on its own. So if the server you’re making the request to isn’t configured to allow OPTIONS requests, that preflight will fail and your browser will never move on to sending the actual POST request you’re trying to send. So the bottom line is, you need to check the server to make sure it has CORS support  configured

Answer (score 0):

When calling an web api from another domain you have to set up the SERVER to to respond with a correct header. The technique is called Cross Origin Resource Sharing. Google for "CORS" and whatever you got on the server .Net/nodejs/PHP...

Comment: Here's a great example of how to implement a server response, web api, in .net I recently used. Works great. [http://www.asp.net/web-api...](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)